# List from nested JSON response

Tags: ios, swift, listview, swift5, xcode11

Im still learning swift and I got stuck on creating list from nested json response. And dont know how to achieve this.

Basically I have json containing array of categories and each categories has array of lifts. What I want to achieve is create list of lifts for each category.

I have no problem to get lifts under specific category within list view with this code:

```
List(data.jsonData.categories[categoryId].lifts) { lift in
```

But dont know how to get all lifts for all categories in the List. I thought to create ForEach above List and just pass index to the [categoryID] but I was getting an error that ForEach could not be used in View.

This is my struct for JSON:

```
// MARK: - Lifts API List
struct liftsAPIList: Codable {
  let categories: [Category]
}

// MARK: - Category
struct Category: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id: Int
  let data: [CategoryLangauge]
  let lifts: [Lift]

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "ID"
    case data, lifts
  }
}

// MARK: - CategoryLangauge
struct CategoryLangauge: Codable {
  let en, fr: [LangaugeCategory]
}

// MARK: - LangaugeCategory
struct LangaugeCategory: Codable {
  let title: String
}

// MARK: - Lift
struct Lift: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id: Int
  let data: [LiftLanguage]

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "ID"
    case data
  }
}

// MARK: - LiftLanguage
struct LiftLanguage: Codable {
  let en, fr: [LangaugeLift]
}

// MARK: - LangaugeLift
struct LangaugeLift: Codable {
  let code, info, photoId, title: String
}
```

Update:

I have figure out with nested forEach inside of list. Dont understand why inside List I can use ForEach but outside I can't

Answer (score 0):

```
List {
                ForEach(self.data.jsonData.categories) { category in

                    Text(category.data[0].en[0].title)

                    ForEach(category.lifts) { lift in

                        Text(lift.data[0].en[0].code)
                    }
                }

            }
```